# Are "method only" or "class only" answers valid?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes I see some answers are in the form "you should use x...", which x is a class (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1748200)) or method (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178600)), and lacks further explantions. Assume the method or class is what the OP looking for, is it a valid answer? If not, should we flag them? or at least discourage them?

(Sorry I don't think they are code only answers because these types of answers even don't contain codes!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is a valid answer.

No, you should not flag them.

Clearly the answer should be expanded on to make it more than just a simple post, but it meets the criteria of answering the question. That is not going to be the best answer to provide, and if you personally feel that the answer is not helpful feel free to vote accordingly.

Also, it is worth mentioning those posts are several years old, and policy has changed over time as well.